# How to read a MP3 audio file into a numpy array / save a numpy array to MP3?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

**Is there a way to read/write a MP3 audio file into/from a `numpy` array with a similar API to [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) and [scipy.io.wavfile.write](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html):**

```
sr, x = wavfile.read('test.wav')
wavfile.write('test2.wav', sr, x)
```

**?**

Note: `pydub`'s `AudioSegment` object doesn't give direct access to a numpy array.

<sup>PS: I have already read [Importing sound files into Python as NumPy arrays (alternatives to audiolab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356779/importing-sound-files-into-python-as-numpy-arrays-alternatives-to-audiolab), tried all the answers, including those which requires to `Popen` ffmpeg and read the content from stdout pipe, etc. I have also read [Trying to convert an mp3 file to a Numpy Array, and ffmpeg just hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192663/trying-to-convert-an-mp3-file-to-a-numpy-array-and-ffmpeg-just-hangs), etc., and tried the main answers, but there was no simple solution. After spending hours on this, I'm posting it here with "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style". I have also read [How to create a numpy array from a pydub AudioSegment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015319/how-to-create-a-numpy-array-from-a-pydub-audiosegment) but this does not easily cover the multi channel case, etc.</sup>

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Calling `ffmpeg` and manually parsing its `stdout` as suggested in many posts about reading a MP3 is a tedious task (many corner cases because different number of channels are possible, etc.), so here is a working solution using `pydub` (you need to `pip install pydub` first).

This code allows to read a MP3 to a numpy array / write a numpy array to a MP3 file **with a similar API than `scipy.io.wavfile.read/write`**:

```
import pydub 
import numpy as np

def read(f, normalized=False):
    """MP3 to numpy array"""
    a = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(f)
    y = np.array(a.get_array_of_samples())
    if a.channels == 2:
        y = y.reshape((-1, 2))
    if normalized:
        return a.frame_rate, np.float32(y) / 2**15
    else:
        return a.frame_rate, y

def write(f, sr, x, normalized=False):
    """numpy array to MP3"""
    channels = 2 if (x.ndim == 2 and x.shape[1] == 2) else 1
    if normalized:  # normalized array - each item should be a float in [-1, 1)
        y = np.int16(x * 2 ** 15)
    else:
        y = np.int16(x)
    song = pydub.AudioSegment(y.tobytes(), frame_rate=sr, sample_width=2, channels=channels)
    song.export(f, format="mp3", bitrate="320k")
```

Notes:

- It only works for 16-bit files for now (even if 24-bit WAV files are pretty common, I've rarely seen 24-bit MP3 files... Does this exist?)
- `normalized=True` allows to work with a float array (each item in [-1,1))

Usage example:

```
sr, x = read('test.mp3')
print(x)

#[[-225  707]
# [-234  782]
# [-205  755]
# ..., 
# [ 303   89]
# [ 337   69]
# [ 274   89]]

write('out2.mp3', sr, x)
```

Comment: Great! For linux users, the output/argument `tags` can be added to read/write to retreive and save metadatas as shown on https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/44 . Add `tags=mediainfo(f).get('TAG', {})` to read and `export(f, format="mp3", bitrate="320k", tags=tags)` to write.

Comment: Some extra dependencies (that can't just be installed with pip on Windows) may be needed in order to use this solution. See https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/348

Answer (score 6):

You can use audio2numpy library.
Install with

```
pip install audio2numpy
```

Then, your code would be:

```py
import audio2numpy as a2n
x,sr=a2n.audio_from_file("test.mp3")
```

For writing, use @Basj 's answer

Comment: These all in one packages are great when just quickly implementing something for an experiment, but in my opinion, using them is even worse than just copy-pasting something like @Basj's answer. (+1 anyways)

Comment: Yes... But it works and if you don't care about speed or efficiency of your code, it's the easiest solution.